# ReactJS - Best payment processer for building a SaaS application

Tags: reactjs, saas

I'm looking to built an event board application where users pay monthly for a subscription and accept payments online for tickets. Anyone have any experience in payment processors that are the best like Stripe, PayPal... any others?

Answer (score 1):

It's a controversial topic. I have a couple of SaaS(~1k users) I run.

In my case, it boiled down to Paddle and Stripe, Paddle lets me avoid a ton of paperwork/accounting because I'd be required to emit an invoice for each customer (which involves collecting address, business ID if any, etc etc), and calculate the correct tax, figure out what do I need to remit, etc etc etc.

While with Paddle/LemonSqueezy I do one invoice a month to them, I already know their details, etc.
LemonSqueezy is more similar to Gumroad and not a direct fit for SaaS/Marketplaces but you can still tweak it alot with their API functionality and a few wrappers.

In case someone wants a refund or a partial refund (say, they forgot to enter a discount coupon), I click a button instead of doing more paperwork.

I pay more in % to sell with Paddle but I think doing a ton of invoices I'd have to pay my accountant more, so I probably save money in the end.

Technically there's not much difference in how to implement payments with both, but Stripe is probably a better product (also probably easier to test with their test mode).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll check out Paddle/LemonSqueezy for sure. I'm assuming Stripe Connect is their solution for this?

Comment: If you are connecting the creator's payment account directly and pay them directly, you can use Stripe Connect. Stripe Connect helps integrate payments into your platform or marketplace. Alternatively, you can use normal Stripe and take payments and then pay creators via separate payouts, transfers, via Paypal etc.

Breakdown of gumroad vs paddle vs lemonsqueezy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gwjtj0_VN1lNlhBjWOxxwhtm0SkoGR9coIZC7s4Nn-8/edit?pli=1#gid=0